# How to find a conditional CDF of a trapezoidal distribution?

Tags: probability, bayesian, uniform-distribution

I'm working on a game theory model of imperfect information, where players observe certain attributes via noisy signals. Specifically, Player 1 has the opportunity to choose any value $\eta$ from the interval $[0, h]$ to transfer to Player 2. $h$, the maximum he may transfer, is drawn from the uniform distribution $U(0,1)$. Player 1 knows $h$, but Player 2 only knows its distribution, and rather than observe it directly, receives a noisy signal $S_h \sim U(h - \epsilon, h + \epsilon)$ about its value. Last, Player 2 also receives a noisy signal $S_\eta \sim U(\eta - \epsilon, \eta + \epsilon)$ about Player 1's choice.

Both players also know:

- $a$ is some constant known to both players. $0 \leq a \leq 1$. $a$ defines the threshold that Player 2 will use to decide how to behave. For example, if $a = .75$, then Player 2 will be cooperative if Player 1 chooses $\eta$ of at least 75% of $h$.
- $\epsilon$ is some number known to both players. $0 < \epsilon \leq 1$.

How can I find the CDF:

$$P(\eta - ah < x \mid S_\eta, S_h, a, \epsilon)$$

This is the probability from Player 2's point of view that Player 1 chose an $\eta$ above the threshold ($ah$) given Player 2's signals $S_\eta$ and $S_h$. Evaluated at 0, this will give $P(\eta < ah \mid S_\eta, S_h, a, \epsilon)$.

I assume you may need a prior about $\eta$ to solve this. Since Player 1 may choose any $\eta \in [0, h]$, I suppose the best to use is just the Uniform distribution $U(0, S_h)$, but I'm really not sure. Since Player 2 doesn't know $h$, it's hard to have a reliable prior distribution. I'm not sure what's normally done in these circumstances.

Thanks!

---

I've posted [about this before](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/196773/how-to-compute-the-cdf-of-this-random-variable), but in that case trying to solve the CDF from Player 1's point of view. In case it's helpful, here is what I found:

$$
P(S_{\eta} - aS_{h} < x \mid \eta, h, a, \epsilon) =
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{ if } x < \eta - \epsilon - ah - a\epsilon \\
\dfrac{1}{8a\epsilon^2}(x - \eta + \epsilon + ah + a\epsilon)^2, & \text{ if } x \in [\eta - \epsilon - ah - a\epsilon, \eta - \epsilon - ah + a\epsilon] \\
\dfrac{a}{2} + \dfrac{1}{2\epsilon}(x-\eta + \epsilon + ah - a\epsilon), & \text{ if } x \in [\eta - \epsilon - ah + a\epsilon, \eta + \epsilon - ah - a\epsilon] \\
1 - \dfrac{1}{8a\epsilon^2}(\eta + \epsilon - ah + a\epsilon - x)^2, & \text{ if } x \in [\eta + \epsilon - ah - a\epsilon, \eta + \epsilon - ah + a\epsilon] \\
1, & \text{ if } x > \eta + \epsilon - ah + a\epsilon \\
\end{cases}
$$

This distribution is trapezoidal, hence the title of the question.

Comment: I think that because $a h$ and $a S_h$ are both uncertain with respect to each other by $a \epsilon$ and because $\eta$ and $S_{\eta}$ are similarly uncertain by $\epsilon$ that the answers are actually the same, just replace $h$ with $S_h$ and $\eta$ with $S_{\eta}$

Comment: Do you know how I might be able to test that with a simulation? The only way I could come up with is to sample randomly from $U(0,1)$ to get an $h$, and then sample randomly from $U(0,h)$ to get an $\eta$. Then find $S_\eta$ and $S_h$ by drawing from $U(\eta-\epsilon, \eta+\epsilon)$ and $U(h-\epsilon, h+\epsilon)$ respectively, and keep track of how many times $\eta < ah$ for each unique $S_h, S_\eta$ pair. The problem is that I think you would have to do this 10^12 times or more to get anything useful.

Comment: I can't really think of any way other that what you suggest.  However, it might be possible to design the experiment a little less randomly (maintaining the distributions) and get clear results with fewer runs.  Let me play with some things in Matlab and I'll try to validate my conjecture :)