Deriving the pdf of noisy signal: sum of pdf f(s)=1/2+s/2 and a uniformly distributed noise
I am having a hard time to find the pdf of $\widetilde{s}=s+x$.
$s$ has a pdf $f(s)=1/2+s/2$ where $s\in(-1,1)$. $x$ is uniformly distributed over $[-\epsilon, \epsilon]$.  I am trying to use the formula for the convolution of distributions.
$f_\widetilde{s}(\widetilde{s}) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_s(s)f_x(\widetilde{s}-s) \,ds $
The steps I have done can be found below, I know something went wrong but cannot tell where.
$\int_{\widetilde{s}-\epsilon}^{\widetilde{s}+\epsilon} f_s(s)\frac{1}{2\epsilon} \,ds$
= $\int_{\widetilde{s}-\epsilon}^{\widetilde{s}+\epsilon} \frac{1}{2}(1+s)\frac{1}{2\epsilon} \,ds$
= $\frac{1}{2}(1+\widetilde{s})$
Please let me know if you know how to find the pdf of $\widetilde{s}$. Thanks a lot!!!

Hi: You need to provide the support of $x$. Otherwise, it's not possible to compute the density.

@mlofton Hi!! $x$ is uniformly distributed over $[-\epsilon, \epsilon]$, where $\epsilon>0$ is very small.

I think the mistake you are making is in the domain of integration. This is because we have two restrictions here: s needs to be between [-1,1] and $[\tilde{s}- \epsilon, \tilde{s} + \epsilon]$.

The threads at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/195433 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/196773 concern simpler versions of this question and both show how to correct your calculations.  The thread at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/332113 concerns a more difficult variant of this question (the product instead of the sum) and the methods given there will easily solve your problem.  Finally, my post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/43075/919 gives an exposition of methods that generally apply to problems like this one.

BTW, this question has nothing to do with [tag:mathematical-statistics].

Fang: I'm going to look at whuber's suggestions so I can hopefully figure it out from those. I suggest you do the same and then write back if you're still stuck. My experience is that whuber's advice will be quite useful.

@whuber: I looked at the various links that you provided but when I tried to relate them to Fang's  particular problem, I failed. I think ( but am not certain ) that this problem is more complicated than the ones that are considered at those links. I found this presentation which led me to that conclusion.  But, the usual disclaimer applies: I could be wrong. https://sas.uwaterloo.ca/~wang/talk/2016Munich.pdf

@mlofton I see this as a FAQ about double integration.  The standard answer is to draw a picture and use indicator variables, as detailed in the duplicates.

@whuber  yes. I went through  most of them. I was thinking the same as far as double integration and you may be correct. But then, when I found that waterloo link, that person was giving a presentation on the EXACT same problem and never provided a solution in his slides. That led me to think that this problem might not be as simple as it may seem. Note that there's no obvious triangle anymore because the minimum's of the uniforms are no longer zero. Maybe someone else will see this thread and provide a solution. I'll take a look at those other links again. I may be missing something obvious.

@mlofton I have provided a general solution at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/43075/919 (look under "Intuition from Probability").  The result is a general one: the PDF of the sum of a uniform random variable (on an interval) with any other random variable with CDF $F$ is the first difference in $F$ (spaced at the length of the uniform interval).  That's very easy to show, as you can check, and doing so will remove any complications related to $F$ itself.

Thanks whuber. I'll check it out. It's much appreciated.
